# recursive onchange event not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have this code, I want to make all dropdowns to be updated once I change the first dropdown. But when I used onchange, only one dropdown updated. For example I change the first dropdown, only 2nd dropdown updated, even I already place onchange event on 2nd dropdown too but it doesn't work.

Here's the code. Thank you for your help.

```js
function myFunction0() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect0").value;
  document.getElementById("mySelect1").value = 'BMW';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
  document.getElementById("mySelect2").value = 'Mercedes';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect0").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

  1
  <select id="mySelect0" onchange="myFunction0()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
      <option value="BMW">BMW
        <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
          <option value="Volvo">Volvo
  </select>
  2
  <select id="mySelect1" onchange="myFunction1()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
      <option value="BMW">BMW
        <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
          <option value="Volvo">Volvo
  </select>
  3
  <select id="mySelect2">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
      <option value="BMW">BMW
        <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
          <option value="Volvo">Volvo
  </select>

  <p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Invalid HTML; `<option>` is not closed

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` or other events don't trigger from setting the value of an element with code, they trigger from a real (user) event in the browser. You'll have to manually trigger those events, manually update the other 2 selects, or find some jquery code for it.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN Event.change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

> Depending on the kind of form element being changed and the way the
>   user interacts with the element, the change event fires at a different
>   moment:
>
> - When the element is activated (by clicking or using the keyboard) for     and ;
> - When the user commits the change explicitly (e.g. by selecting a    value from a 's dropdown with a mouse click, by selecting a
>     date from a date picker for , by selecting a file
>     in the file picker for , etc.);
> - When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not    commited (e.g. after editing the value of  or 
>     type="text">).

So use javascript to change the value won't trigger that `change` event.
But you can still create a change event then trigger it from the target.

```js
function myFunction0() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect0").value;
  document.getElementById("mySelect1").value = 'BMW';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
  // Trigger change event on mySelect1
  document.getElementById("mySelect1").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
  document.getElementById("mySelect2").value = 'Mercedes';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
  // Trigger change event on mySelect2
  document.getElementById("mySelect2").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}

function myFunction2() {
  console.log(x);
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect0").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

  1
  <select id="mySelect0" onchange="myFunction0()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo
  </select>
  2
  <select id="mySelect1" onchange="myFunction1()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo
  </select>
  3
  <select id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction2()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo
  </select>

  <p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```